# == Exception caught by image resource service ==

Tags: flutter, image, dart, mobile

I am facing a problem when I run my Flutter project on the emulator. The project is not working well and some of the images and icons are not showing. This is the output. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI
 
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2751:9)
#1      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2622:7)
#2      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:63:38)
#3      HttpFileService.get (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/file_service.dart:37:44)
#4      WebHelper._download (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:115:24)
#5      WebHelper._updateFile (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:97:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      WebHelper._downloadOrAddToQueue (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:65:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0) 
 Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0): CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: It may happens due to empty url going in `CatchNetworkImageProvider` .

Answer (score 0):

```
CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0)
```

According to the documentation of [CachedNetworkImageProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/cached_network_image/latest/cached_network_image/CachedNetworkImageProvider-class.html), the first parameter should be the url from which to load the image. But `""` is not a valid web URL.

You should pass a valid URL to the constructor instead.